# arm assembly loop data sets

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I am a beginner in ARM7 assembly (using KEIL microVision4). The program i have has a main data set named INPUT and three reference data sets named OUTPUT1,2,3,4,5,6. Some calculations have to be made (which i already figured out in the code) between INPUT and OUTPUT1,2,3,4,5,6 and the result has to be stored. I am able to workout betweeen INPUT and **ONE OF THE** DATA SETS (output 1,2, 3,4,5,6). What do i need to do in order to for the program to work with all data sets, like if the number of data set changes the program still works without any change in instructions?

```
                                     AREA pj, CODE, Readonly
                                                  
                                     ENTRY
E                                       EQU     10 ;number of elements
S                                       EQU     6  ;number of sets
                                    
                                     MOV r0, #E ;number of elements in the data set
                                     MOV r1, #S ;number of data sets
                                     LDR r2, =INPUT ;source
                                     LDR r3, =OUTPUT1
                                     MOV r5, #0 ;running sum
                                    
method                               LDR r6, [r2], #4 ;LOADS THE SOURCE
                                     LDR r7, [r3], #4 ;LOADS THE OUTPUT1 DATA SET
                                     SUB r7, r6, r7
                                     ADD r5, r5, r7
                                     SUBS r0, r0, #1 ;DECREMENT
                                     BNE method
                                    
                                    
                                    
 stop                   B stop



 INPUT                         DCD 39,139,13,2,2,5,1,2,3,5
         
 OUTPUT1                       DCD -50,-30,-20,-12,-124,-123,-123,-127,-7,93
 OUTPUT2                       DCD 23,142,123,1,2,5,192,93,73,12
 OUTPUT3                       DCD -5,123,12,5,12,2,5,1,2,4
 OUTPUT4                       DCD 43,23,12,1,3,5,1,2,4,5
 OUTPUT5                       DCD 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
 OUTPUT6                       DCD 4,1,2,4,12,2,4,5,1,2
                               END
```

Comment: Calculate the base address of the output as `output + number_of_elements * output_index * 4`

Comment: @Jester , hmm i believe i get what you're saying, i'll try it. Didn't think about it before.